# Upgraded to Xcode 13 RC, and latest RevenueCat package, and now Purchases won't work with watchOS

Tags: swift, xcode, watchkit, revenuecat

I have an independent watch app on the store as part of a family of apps. The watch app is part of a single project with the iOS app. After I upgraded Xcode, my app will no longer recognize the Purchases(now RevenueCat) package. I am using a single class that manages the purchases. If I have it as part of the watch extension it throws errors. If I only target the iOS app, the errors go away. The errors all essentially amount to:

```
'PurchaserInfo' is not a member type of class 'RevenueCat.Purchases'
```

I am also showing an error of

```
Watch Extension.build/Objects-normal/arm64_32/Settings.dia:1:1: warning: Could not read serialized diagnostics file: error("Invalid diagnostics signature") (in target 'Watch Extension'…
```

Steps I have done:

1. Make sure that the package is linked to the extension
2. Cleared the derived data, cleaned the project and restarted.

I can find no setting that seems to be a problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the changes in `purchases-ios` version 4.0.0.
The type `Purchases.PurchaserInfo` has been updated, it's now just `PurchaserInfo` (you can also refer to it as `RevenueCat.PurchaserInfo`).

The update is documented in the following link:

https://github.com/RevenueCat/purchases-ios/blob/4.0.0-beta.1/docs/V4_API_Updates.md#type-changes-for-swift

There are more changes along the same lines, like `Purchases.Offerings` -> `Offerings`, `Purchases.package` -> `package`.

Updating those should help with the migration.

If you're not ready to migrate yet, you can also stick with version 3.12.4 until you're ready.

Comment: I didn't check to see if they had renamed as it compiled with the iOS application. Vary strange.

Comment: After fixing the RC errors, and cleaning the build folder, deleting derivedData, restarting, fixing a recursive copy bundle resource issue that cropped up, it builds. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks very much for sharing that documentation link. I was experiencing a similar issue in Mac Catalyst.